# How to create badges automatically on repo creation in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I am currently creating a template repository, containing a basic project structure to be used by our team when creating new repositories. The final step is to **git push origin master** the new project to create a new gitlab repository. The main workflow is functional.

I do not see an easy option, however, to programatically create badges.

- I know that I can use gitlab's API to create badges but I am not sure how to set it up.
- Is there a way to run a pipeline on repository creation as a rule?

I would appreciate any pointers a lot.